# Why is flow erroring when using a switch statement to loop over keys in an object?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This is obviously a contrived example but I don't understand why flow is erroring in this case. The error I'm receiving from flow is on the call of `map`. It says the mothod cannot be called on a possibly undefined value.

You can see the error in [flows live editor here.](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN6pi1gC2WAggE4sCGWA-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-Ddx5OTI8yElCru6Kn05mwABqMAVcYVHd10UaxVBXNIjxEYE8C8eAZBMNkRHPECwLoTdY1AsVljwKBvhgDAA0DNDtyNfdijaYDVH3TBjAwExKAJS0+EuCoLgqG4KOo0xKA4oA)

The two things I'm not clear on is (questions repeated in code example as inline comments)
i. Should I even have to check that `foo[key]` is an array? 
ii. Why does the flow error go away if I change the first break statement into a return statement?

```
/* @flow */

type Foo = {
    myArray?: Array<string>
};

function test(foo: Foo) {

    Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {

        switch (key) {
            case "myArray":
                /**
                  QUESTION 1:
                  I shouldn't have to check that foo[key] is an array because I've told flow that when I do
                  have a key called myArray it's going to be an array. If I remove this if statement
                  I get an error saying that I could be calling
                  */
                if (!Array.isArray(foo[key])) {
                    /**
                      QUESTION 2:
                      If I change this break statement to a return statement instead, flow linting passes and
                      it doesn't complain about the .map call below. Why?
                      */
                    break;
                }

                const result = foo[key].map(s => {
                    return s + "1";
                });

                console.log(result);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    });
}

test({ myArray: ["foo"]});
test({});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QUESTION 1: You don't need to check for array type. Just check value for null.

(Type of value and result are for examples. They can be removed)

```js
const value: ?Array<string> = foo[key];
if (value == null)
    break;

const result: Array<string> = value.map(s => {
    return s + "1";
});
```

[try flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN6pi1gC2WAggE4sCGWA-AFxiscsAHgDOGFgEsAdgHMAfKgC+AbnRQArlIDGGCXClgMeMQAooJPsTgBKKujpgA8gCMAVnh0A6ANZ4sIsxJrT3MWAFF2LQALE18scjk7Ggc6EQQJDGiwWL9bahSCsC12EQIAIkYBTjKeZMLCrX0xMAA3dhh1PD4uKuExSVlEinM4AG04gF1VevqJKGy2joIyCil1GBhrOpmC5xY8dm9VbZ3aRqlm-ZF1jD5e0XFpeXJW9s7PenYcExEEu1PCvsMOoWAZfgBqMBlACMZWmALoimsxwRdHOIjgMDwnngMhMVxuyJOpz2ByO9lOABM8FB2DdaqjaKTDvCCooKbQkap2ZhjBgTJQGMw2Jw+KMyiMyhMubzTJQuUA)

QUESTION 2: If value check for null, no flow errors happens.
Probably flow handles differently break and return statements.

It is better to prefer `break` over `return` inside `switch` inside `loop`. If forEach refactored to for(...) loop then `return` behavior is changed.

P.S. `Object.assign`'s type definition seems to be broken
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1149

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer about checking null. Even if I do what you said (and additionally type the result of `foo[key]`) it still errors. Can you update with a working flow.org/try link?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something to do with Flow not being able to be sure that `foo` is not being mutated from outside the function. By creating a local shallow copy of `foo` everything is fine.

```
/* @flow */

type Foo = {
    myArray?: Array<string>
};

function test(foo: Foo) {

    const localFoo = Object.assign({}, foo);

    Object.keys(localFoo).forEach(key => {

        switch (key) {
            case "myArray":

                const result = localFoo[key].map(s => {
                    return s + "1";
                });

                console.log(result);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    });
}

test({ myArray: ["foo"]});
test({});
```